# Make values not adjacent to each other NA

Tags: r

The values >=10 in the data frame below (values 31,89,12,69) does sometimes come in order like 89 and 12. By that I mean de order 123456789, they are adjacent to eachother. I would like to make the values which are not adjacent to each other(31,69, in 31 nr 2 is missing in between to be in order, for 69, nr 7 and8 are missing to be in order) NA. How to code this? Imagine a big dataset! :)

```
 id <- factor(rep(letters[1:2], each=5))
    A <- c(1,2,NA,67,8,9,0,6,7,9)
    B <- c(5,6,31,9,8,1,NA,9,7,4)
    C <- c(2,3,5,NA,NA,2,7,6,4,6)
    D <- c(6,5,89,3,2,9,NA,12,69,8)
    df <- data.frame(id, A, B,C,D) 
    df
  id  A  B  C  D
1   a  1  5  2  6
2   a  2  6  3  5
3   a NA 31  5 89
4   a 67  9 NA  3
5   a  8  8 NA  2
6   b  9  1  2  9
7   b  0 NA  7 NA
8   b  6  9  6 12
9   b  7  7  4 69
10  b  9  4  6  8
```

It should look like:

```
 id  A  B  C  D
1   a  1  5  2  6
2   a  2  6  3  5
3   a NA NA  5 89
4   a 67  9 NA  3
5   a  8  8 NA  2
6   b  9  1  2  9
7   b  0 NA  7 NA
8   b  6  9  6 12
9   b  7  7  4 NA
10  b  9  4  6  8
```

Comment: What is the algorithm for this? It's not clear to me what single and double values mean in this context.

Comment: @ Roman Luštrik Question is updated!

Comment: still not very clear. So when you say *chars >1* you actually mean 'value >= 10' right? Also why do you convert 69 to NA and not 12?

Comment: @Sotos Yes when I say <1 I mean up to >=10. Im thinking the order of the numbers123456789, the values comes after each other numerically. 12 does come after each other ( 1 then 2) but 69 does not ( 6 and 9, it missing 7 and 8 to be in order). :)

Comment: Do you have only two digit numbers? Or it can be more number of digits as well?

Comment: @Ronak shah Yes there could be more! Do you have suggestions of how to code that? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution defining a vector of the values to keep beforehand (only up to two-digit numbers, but could be extended):

```
numerals <- 1:9
vector <- 0:9
for (i in numerals) {
  j <- numerals[i+1]
  if (!is.na(j)) {
    number <- as.numeric(paste(c(i, j), collapse = ""))
    number_reverse <- as.numeric(paste(c(j, i), collapse = ""))
    vector <- c(vector, number, number_reverse)
  }
}

vector
[1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 12 21 23 32 34 43 45 54 56 65 67 76 78 87 89 98
```

Function to replace number if not in `vector`:

```
replace <- function(x) {
  x <- ifelse(!x %in% vector, NA, x)
  return(x)
}
```

Result:

```
df %>% mutate_at(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), replace)

   id  A  B  C  D
1   a  1  5  2  6
2   a  2  6  3  5
3   a NA NA  5 89
4   a 67  9 NA  3
5   a  8  8 NA  2
6   b  9  1  2  9
7   b  0 NA  7 NA
8   b  6  9  6 12
9   b  7  7  4 NA
10  b  9  4  6  8
```

Comment: @great! I forgot to mention it could also be 43,65,87 and so on, in the opposite direction so to say. How to fix this?

Comment: Easily fixed by creating another variable called `number_reverse` in the `if` condition. Edited my code.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function that tests individual numbers

```
MyFunction <- function(A){
  NumbersToCheck <- lapply(strsplit(as.character(A),""),as.integer)
  check <- lapply(2:length(unlist(NumbersToCheck)), function(X) ifelse(NumbersToCheck[[1]][X]-NumbersToCheck[[1]][X-1]==1,TRUE,FALSE))
  return(ifelse(FALSE %in% check,NA,A))
}
```

Which can then be applied to your entire df as follows

```
df[,2:ncol(df)] <- lapply(2:ncol(df),  function(X) unlist(lapply(df[,X],MyFunction)))
```

to get the following result

```
> df
   id  A  B  C  D
1   a  1  5  2  6
2   a  2  6  3  5
3   a NA NA  5 89
4   a 67  9 NA  3
5   a  8  8 NA  2
6   b  9  1  2  9
7   b  0 NA  7 NA
8   b  6  9  6 12
9   b  7  7  4 NA
10  b  9  4  6  8
```

Comment: Thanks! But 69 did get NA...?

Comment: Good catch, I had originally misread your question and was only checking to see if the numbers were in order (next digit larger than the previous). I have edited my answer to check for only "adjacent" digits.

Answer (score 1):

```r
df[] <- lapply(df, function(col) {
  # Split each value character by character
  NAs <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(col), split = ""), function(chars) {
    # Convert them back to integer to compare with `diff`
    # and verify the increment is always 1 or -1
    diff <- diff(as.integer(chars))
    !all(diff == 1) && !all(diff == -1)
  })
  # If not, replace those values with NA
  col[NAs] <- NA
  col
})
#> Warning in diff(as.integer(chars)): NAs introduced by coercion

#> Warning in diff(as.integer(chars)): NAs introduced by coercion

#> ...

#> Warning in diff(as.integer(chars)): NAs introduced by coercion
df
#>    id  A  B  C  D
#> 1   a  1  5  2  6
#> 2   a  2  6  3  5
#> 3   a NA NA  5 89
#> 4   a 67  9 NA  3
#> 5   a  8  8 NA  2
#> 6   b  9  1  2  9
#> 7   b  0 NA  7 NA
#> 8   b  6  9  6 12
#> 9   b  7  7  4 NA
#> 10  b  9  4  6  8
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: @ Aurèle Thanks! And really nice with the explanation to the code!

Comment: You're welcome. Also see my edit to address the "opposite direction" case